# MaterializeCSS - Is it possible to center the navbar?

Tags: css, materialize

I am using MaterializeCSS. My site has navigation centered on top and the site logo below that. Please see image:
[Webpage layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VG5wg.png)

I tried a lot but I couldn't center it. 
Kindly let me know how it is possible.

Comment: Could you show your code? Try it on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38964113/how-can-i-create-a-navbar-with-center-aligned-links-using-materialize/42890059#42890059

Answer (score 1):

Not by default, you will probably need to remove the logo and create a class for navbar that removes the float and set the margin to:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Comment: can you give a jsfiddle example? i can't seem to get it.