# How can i create a navbar with center aligned links using Materialize?

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am trying to build a 1 page vertical scrolling website with a navbar at the top using materialize, now,  materialize only has classes to align the links either left or right, a logo can be center aligned but not the links themselves,

I've been adding center-align, and center classes to the UL and a wrapper div, and also, tried using the grid without success, here is my code:

HTML

```
   <div class="navbar-fixed"  >
    <nav id="nav_f" class="transparent z-depth-0" role="navigation" >
        <div class="container">



            <div class="nav-wrapper"  >

             <div class="row s12">

            <div>
                  <ul class="hide-on-med-and-down navbar " >
                      <li><a id="desk-about-us" href="#about-us">ABOUT US</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#how-it-works">HOW IT WORKS</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#comments">COMMENTS</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>

                <ul id="nav-mobile" class="side-nav side-nav-menu ">
                    <li><a href="#about-us">ABOUT US</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#how-it-works">HOW IT WORKS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#comments">COMMENTS</a></li>
                </ul>
            <a href="#" data-activates="nav-mobile" class="button-collapse right"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
            </div>

       </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

On my css there is only an underline for the hovering behavior of the links and the background color,

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Materialize comes with a `float: left` on all `nav ul li` elements. If you try to center them with the standard [Helper](http://materializecss.com/helpers.html), it won't work. So, in addition to `text-align: center`, you'll have to set that `float` to `none`. However, that will make all of your buttons stack atop each other; to solve that, simply have the `<li>` elements display inline and the `<a>` elements display inline-block.

I suggest creating a new class as such:

```
nav.nav-center ul {
    text-align: center;
}
nav.nav-center ul li {
    display: inline;
    float: none;
}
nav.nav-center ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Use the standard Materialize `<nav>` component with the `.nav-center` class above:

```
<nav class="nav-center" role="navigation">
    <div class="nav-wrapper container">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="/help">Help</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 4):

The official answer is likely that navbar links should be either left or right aligned, to indicate functionality, as per the material design guidelines: https://material.google.com/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar

however, you can get around this in a somewhat hacky way:

```
<div class="naxbar-fixed">
    <nav>   
        <div class="brand-logo center">
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="/page1">page1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/page2">page2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

by wrapping your navbar in an a div with classes brand-logo and center you're tricking materialize into thinking the menu is a logo and it will allow the links to be centered.

I believe such a menu would disappear on a small enough screen and may not behave how you want it to.

You can use materialize tabs instead:

```
<div class="naxbar-fixed">
    <nav>
        <div class="white-text">
            <ul class="tabs center" style="width:20em;">
                <li class="tab col s6 active>
                    <a href="/page1">page1a>
                </li>
                <li class="tab col s6">
                    <a href="/page2">page2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

This has the advantage of giving each link and equal width but will likely require you to do a bit of extra styling and may require more work if you're concerned with mobile.

Answer (score 1):

So, i solved this by adding the following transform to my UL element:

```
nav ul{
  transform: translateX(32%);
  webkit-transform: translateX(-32%);
}
```

Since my links take up around 1 3rd of the screen the transform is  to move them just 1 3rd to the left.

Answer (score 0):

Removing float and setting text-align to center wasn't the best solution for me when I added a dropdown to my nav. Some of the dropdown links where aligned to left, some to center. I think an easy solution is to create a class with `display: flex` and `justify-content: center`. I put it in the ul along with the `hide-on-med-and-down` class so that centering doesn't affect the position of the mobile menu button.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav');
    var instances = M.Sidenav.init(elems, {});
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-trigger');
    var instances = M.Dropdown.init(elems, {
        coverTrigger: false
    });
});
```

```css
.nav-center {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Dropdown Content -->
<ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
  <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- Navbar  -->
<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <ul class="nav-center">
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
          <li><a class="dropdown-trigger" href="#!" data-target="dropdown1">Dropdown</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```